# How to suppress IE9 window.close() confirm message

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

After applying the window.close function IE9 raises the "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close ..." message. Is there a way to suppress this message without changing the application code, but by changing some IE-specific registry entries instead?

Answer (score 7):

IE doesnt allow to close the window without confirmation if the window was not opened by script
U can try this ...

    `window.open('', '_self', '');

     window.close();`

Comment: +1 The `window.open('', '_self', '');` worked for me. I'd love to know why though. I am forced to use IE8 but it also seems to work with IE9.

Comment: cool, work a fine `window.open('','_self','').close();` thanks