# Issue with popups in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

All -

We have surveys on our website, which opens a popup on window unload. The JavaScript code to open the popup is as follows

```
window.open(URL,'testpopup','toolbar=no,personalbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=775,height=565,screenX=1,screenY=1,top=1,left=1')
```

The issue is in IE10, when the popup opens in a new tab. The popup has two options 'accept' and 'decline'. When the user clicks on 'decline', it is crashing the entire browser. Here is the close code. I did not see this behavior on my computer, but lot of users have reported this issue

```
<a href="javascript:window.close(self)">Decline</a>
```

Could anyone suggest what the issue could be?

Comment: Most web browsers have a setting that controls how pop ups are opened, that would be the first thing I would check.

Comment: yes, I do see settings in IE options to decide how a popup should open. But is there something code wise we can do, as it is not quite possible to suggest this solution (of changing their browser settings) to users.

Comment: No idea what could cause that, especially since it's not reproducible. One thing you might try just for fun is the answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375679/how-to-suppress-ie9-window-close-confirm-message): `window.open('', '_self', '');window.close();` That shouldn't work, but you never know - maybe somewhere along the line IE gets confused and you need to remind it that this is just a popup.